# Routing Remap Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

I'm using Laravel 4, I'm trying to create a cms pages which the urls look like : `domain.tld/en/how-it-works`. they are created using a backoffice and I fetch it using the slug `how-it-works` and the current language . The problem is that if I want to access to `domain.tld/login` (which is a static page) it shows me a 404 page, of course because the page is not found in the database. So I'm looking for a solution which looks in the other routes if the given slug is not found.

Please any help.

And sorry for my english.

This my routes.php file

```
$languages = array('fr', 'en');
$locale = Request::segment(1);
if(in_array($locale, $languages)){
\App::setLocale($locale);
}else{
$locale = null;
}

 Route::group(array('prefix' => $locale), function()
 {


  Route::get('/', array('before' => 'loginCookie',  'uses' => 'HomeController@getIndex', 'as' => '/'));

Route::get('{slug}',array('uses' => 'ArticleController@getArticle', 'as' => 'articles.show'));

  Route::group(array('prefix' => 'login'), function() {
        Route::get('/',  array('before' => 'guest', 'after' => 'reflashPool', 'uses' => 'UserController@getLogin'));
        Route::post('/',array('before' => 'guest|csrf','after' => 'reflashPool', 'uses' => 'UserController@postLogin'));
        Route::get('remind-password',array('uses' => 'UserController@getRemind'));
        Route::post('remind-password','UserController@postRemind');
        Route::get('reset-password/{token}','UserController@getReset');
        Route::post('reset-password','UserController@postReset');
    });
```

Comment: post your routes file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be as fast as possible, Laravel process routes in the order you write them and the first one which met the requirement is the one it choses.

So, you just have to make your most generic route the last one:

```
 Route::group(array('prefix' => $locale), function()
 {

    Route::get('/', array('before' => 'loginCookie',  'uses' => 'HomeController@getIndex', 'as' => '/'));

    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'login'), function() {
        Route::get('/',  array('before' => 'guest', 'after' => 'reflashPool', 'uses' => 'UserController@getLogin'));
        Route::post('/',array('before' => 'guest|csrf','after' => 'reflashPool', 'uses' => 'UserController@postLogin'));
        Route::get('remind-password',array('uses' => 'UserController@getRemind'));
        Route::post('remind-password','UserController@postRemind');
        Route::get('reset-password/{token}','UserController@getReset');
        Route::post('reset-password','UserController@postReset');
    });

    Route::get('{slug}',array('uses' => 'ArticleController@getArticle', 'as' => 'articles.show'));

});
```

Comment: I have a question , assuming I using two tables  (two controllers), if the first failed, how can I search into the second one. ?